# What exercises should be done post-op for a tongue tied 2 week old?

Tags: newborn, health, ankyloglossia

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are there things to watch out for after a tongue-tie operation?](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/1823/are-there-things-to-watch-out-for-after-a-tongue-tie-operation)

My 2 week old daughter got the clipping procedure to fix her tongue-tie.
What exercises need to be done by me on her?

Just to add that the paediatrician recommended me to find the exercises on the internet! I see a link to "[Are there things to watch out for after a tongue-tie operation?](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/1823/are-there-things-to-watch-out-for-after-a-tongue-tie-operation)" but the exercises there are for 6 year olds who can do the exercises themselves. I'm looking for ones for a 2 week old where I'd have to do them manually.

Comment: Actually, if Brendan's okay with it, it seems like the top answer on there is appropriate as well: "Ask your doctor".

Comment: I'm now closing this question because it's a duplicate, and the earlier question appear equally valid for a newborn.